# Appending to merged async generators in Python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm trying to merge a bunch of asynchronous generators in Python 3.7 while still adding new async generators on iteration. I'm currently using `aiostream` to merge my generators:

```
from asyncio import sleep, run
from aiostream.stream import merge

async def go():
    yield 0
    await sleep(1)
    yield 50
    await sleep(1)
    yield 100

async def main():
    tasks = merge(go(), go(), go())

    async for v in tasks:
        print(v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(main())
```

However, I need to be able to continue to add to the running tasks once the loop has begun. Something like.

```
from asyncio import sleep, run
from aiostream.stream import merge

async def go():
    yield 0
    await sleep(1)
    yield 50
    await sleep(1)
    yield 100

async def main():
    tasks = merge(go(), go(), go())

    async for v in tasks:
        if v == 50:
            tasks.merge(go())
        print(v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(main())
```

The closest I've got to this is using the `aiostream` library but maybe this can also be written fairly neatly with just the native `asyncio` standard library.

Comment: If you are already using `aiostream` to merge the generators, and you have managed to add to running tasks, then why not retain that solution? Merging a _fixed_ number of tasks is possible, but [not trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50975690/1600898) using stock asyncio. You can use that implementation as a starting point if you need to add support for additional iterators.

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If you are asking why don't I just append the extra go calls before I start iterating then my answer would be: this is a contrived example simplifying my use-case. I do not know all the tasks to be performed when I start the loop they are determined by the results of other tasks. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Based on the last sentence of your question ("The closest I've got to this is using the `aiostream` library"), I got the impression that you solved the problem using `aiostreams`, so I was wondering why you're not satisfied with that solution?

Comment: Nope sorry, I was saying that the closest I got to getting the functionality that I want (merging multiple async generators) was using that library but it doesn't support adding more tasks later. So not full satisfied the requirement. I wanted to mention that I realise aiostream might not be the right tool for the job, but it at least gives me the syntax to express the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an implementation that should work efficiently even with a large number of async iterators:

```
class merge:
    def __init__(self, *iterables):
        self._iterables = list(iterables)
        self._wakeup = asyncio.Event()

    def _add_iters(self, next_futs, on_done):
        for it in self._iterables:
            it = it.__aiter__()
            nfut = asyncio.ensure_future(it.__anext__())
            nfut.add_done_callback(on_done)
            next_futs[nfut] = it
        del self._iterables[:]
        return next_futs

    async def __aiter__(self):
        done = {}
        next_futs = {}
        def on_done(nfut):
            done[nfut] = next_futs.pop(nfut)
            self._wakeup.set()

        self._add_iters(next_futs, on_done)
        try:
            while next_futs:
                await self._wakeup.wait()
                self._wakeup.clear()
                for nfut, it in done.items():
                    try:
                        ret = nfut.result()
                    except StopAsyncIteration:
                        continue
                    self._iterables.append(it)
                    yield ret
                done.clear()
                if self._iterables:
                    self._add_iters(next_futs, on_done)
        finally:
            # if the generator exits with an exception, or if the caller stops
            # iterating, make sure our callbacks are removed
            for nfut in next_futs:
                nfut.remove_done_callback(on_done)

    def append_iter(self, new_iter):
        self._iterables.append(new_iter)
        self._wakeup.set()
```

The only change required for your sample code is that the method is named `append_iter`, not `merge`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [stream.flatten](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#aiostream.stream.flatten) with an asyncio queue to store the new generators.

```
import asyncio
from aiostream import stream, pipe

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await queue.put(go())
    await queue.put(go())
    await queue.put(go())

    xs = stream.call(queue.get)
    ys = stream.cycle(xs)
    zs = stream.flatten(ys, task_limit=5)
    async with zs.stream() as streamer:
        async for item in streamer:
            if item == 50:
                await queue.put(go())
            print(item)
```

Notice that you may tune the number of tasks that can run at the same time using the `task_limit` argument. Also note that `zs` can be elegantly defined using the pipe syntax:

```
zs = stream.call(queue.get) | pipe.cycle() | pipe.flatten(task_limit=5)
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the project maintainer.</sub>